# KSOAP2: get http status code for a response of a web service

Tags: android, ksoap

I need to get a http status code from ksoap response to specify exceptions like 403-unauthorized (I use client certificates for authentication - when a certificate is not  valid).
I was trying to find a http status within ResponseProperties (where it should be I think), but I didn't.

Code:

```
...
HttpsTransportSE transport=new HttpsTransportSE(host, port, service, timeout);
try {
  SoapObject request=new SoapObject(namespace, method);
  request.addProperty("param", param);

  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.dotNet=true;
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

  transport.call(getStatusAction, envelope);
  SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
  nRet=Integer.parseInt(response.toString());
}
catch(Exception e) {
  // Here I can get HeaderProperties by transport.getConnection().getResponseProperties();
  // But http status code is not present
  e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    URL myurl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = myurl.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(20 * 1000);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
    int responseCode = -1;

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        httpConnection.disconnect();
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);
        //...
    }
    else if(...)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks breceivemail, but I'm using KSOAP2 and doesn't have direct access to HttpURLConnection. Updated question with a sample code.

Comment: Aha...you ment it as a pre-check before calling some SOAP code. Thanks, I tried, it's helpful. When I don't send a client certificate, I got correct 403 response. However, when my certificate is not present in server configuration, I don't got 401-Unauthorized, but IOException "Received authentication challenge is null" is thrown. It's clear, but 401 would be precise.

Comment: so select it as answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Must say I don't agree with this answer. Performing 2 network calls instead of 1 and parsing an IOException just sounds a bit overkill to me.

Comment: where is the code to get http status code in this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Coming in very late to the game, not many people using SOAP these days...

You can get the HTTP response code when you catch org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException instead of Exception

```
} catch (HttpResponseException httpException) {
    int statusCode = httpException.getStatusCode();
    List responseHeaders = httpException.getResponseHeaders();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The response headers are header property objects, e.g.

```
0 = {HeaderProperty@4668} 
 key = null
 value = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
1 = {HeaderProperty@4669} 
 key = "Content-Length"
 value = "0"
```